# Can I only stop OneDrive memorable photos to show up?

Tags: onedrive, notifications

It seems that the `OneDrive` is always showing notifications of historical photos (`Look back at your memories`) from time to time in the `Windows` Notifications. I want to disable it, but still keep the other important OneDriver notice, is that possible?

Comment: Please go to white OneDrive icon > Help & Seetings > Settings > Settings tab > Notifications, check whether you untick the box of "[On this day" memories are available notifications.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDF44.png)"

Comment: yes! Can you answer it below so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ lanselibai Thank you very much.

Please click white OneDrive icon on task bar > Help & Seetings > Settings > Settings tab > Notifications, check whether you untick the box of "On this day" memories are available notifications."

[image]